# ObsoleteAttribute confusion

Tags: c#, properties, attributes, obsolete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are C# collection-properties not flagged as obsolete when calling properties on them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577132/why-are-c-sharp-collection-properties-not-flagged-as-obsolete-when-calling-prope)

I would like to apply ObsoleteAttribute to a property, but it seems that compiler generates warnings/errors only for direct usage of attribute, any indirect usage is silently ignored.

I think the following example illustrates the problem very well:

```
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var o = new Old();
        Console.WriteLine(o.Geezer); // compilation fails: 'ObsoleteAttributeTest.Program.Old.Geezer' is obsolete: 'Some error' 
        Console.WriteLine(o.Geezer.Attributes); // compiles OK
    }

    class Old
    {
        [ObsoleteAttribute("Some error", true)]
        public System.Xml.XmlElement Geezer { get { return null; } }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seconded; MS link: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=417159

Comment: 3 minutes, now that's impressive, thank you folks!
Sorry about submitting duplicate :/

Comment: Official response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577132/why-are-c-collection-properties-not-flagged-as-obsolete-when-calling-properties/652824#652824

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a known bug in the latest C# compiler (C# 3.0). There is [another question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577132/why-are-c-collection-properties-not-flagged-as-obsolete-when-calling-properties) relating to this problem.