# Visual Studio 2008 does not show any "obsolete"-warnings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, .net-2.0, migration, .net-1.1

**Duplicate:** [Why are C# collection-properties not flagged as obsolete when calling properties on them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577132/why-are-c-collection-properties-not-flagged-as-obsolete-when-calling-properties)

I just migrated a .NET 1.1 project to .NET 2.0 using Visual Studio 2008. I know that there are references to obsolete methods in the project.

But Visual Studio does not show "obsolete"-warnings after building. The build succeeds and shows only 3 warnings from members that are assigned a value that is never used. When I remove these members there are no warnings at all.

I NEED THESE "OBSOLETE"-WARNINGS

The Warning level is 4 (maximum), Warnings are enabled.

Just one sample:

```
protected internal DataConnector()
{
    _connectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ProductConnectionString"];
}
```

All references that should result in an "obsolete"-warning are to members of classes of the .NET Framework.

Comment: Can you givte a code sample and the APi which is obsolete?

Comment: This is a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577132/why-are-c-collection-properties-not-flagged-as-obsolete-when-calling-properties

Comment: @JaredPar, I added a code sample, the API is .NET, here the all-time-classic AppSettings vs. ConfigurationManager

@Jeff Yates: Thank you, but I'm not sure it is really a duplicate: I just call .NET members, no members of my own code that are obsolete. Plus, I get no "obsolete"-warnings at all ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeff Yates is right, this is a duplicate to [Why are C# collection-properties not flagged as obsolete when calling properties on them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577132/why-are-c-collection-properties-not-flagged-as-obsolete-when-calling-properties)

It is a bug in the C# 3.5 compiler reported here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=417159

I checked it: copied the csc.exe commandline from the output window to a cmd-console. When I change the directory to the .NET 2.0 directory (using C# 2.0 compiler), it shows the warnings. Microsoft knows this bug and fixed it in C# 4.0 but will not fix it in the 3.5 version.

Comment: Not on my 3.5sp1!  I still get the warnings.

Comment: "... fixed it in C# 4.0 but will NOT fix it in the 3.5 version"

Answer (score 0):

Is the code calling the obsolete method(s) itself flagged as obsolete?

Comment: No, it has no ObsoleteAttribute.

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a shot in the dark here, but is the usage of an obsolete member taking place in a project that you're REFERENCING, and when you're building it isn't actually rebuilding that project? If that's a possibility, I would try manually building the project where the usage is taking place, or just rebuilding the entire solution.

Comment: Already tried rebulding the Solution or just the Project, no change

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are doing a full build on the project, not just an incremental build.

Comment: How do I do this? I used "Rebuild", is that enough?